# Can't build a Skia module (SkPlainTextEditor)

Tags: build, ninja, skia, gn

I'm trying to build Skia's `modules/skplaintexteditor`:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/skia/+/master/modules/skplaintexteditor/

---

I have followed the instructions in [README.md](https://chromium.googlesource.com/skia/+/master/modules/skplaintexteditor/README.md):

```
tools/git-sync-deps
bin/gn gen out/default
ninja -C out/default editor
```

The first two commands are working, but the ninja build is failing with:

```
ninja: error: unknown target 'editor'
```

Skia itself is building fine (i.e. if I don't specify the `editor` target in the `ninja` command).

---

What is missing here? How do I build `skplaintexteditor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brian Osman answered in this topic on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skia-discuss/2Atp9B4UVOo):

> Currently, all of our "test" tools (which includes experimental modules like the editor) fall under the skia_enable_tools umbrella. That requires gpu support (skia_enable_gpu = true), and static linking (is_component_build = false). The logic to enforce this is at the end of gn/skia.gni. Some of the experimental modules used by the editor use private Skia APIs, so those modules don't handle component builds correctly.

So, adding the arguments:

```
is_component_build = false
skia_enable_gpu = true
```

fixes the build.